# How to retrieve required values from a kubeconfig file from AKS and give as values in a terraform script?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-devops, azure, azure-kubernetes-service

I'm trying to automate the creation of infrastructure - azurerm_container_registry, azurerm_kubernetes_cluster, azurerm_role_assignment (to pull the image from ACR) using one terraform script and in the another terraform script, I'm trying to automate service connections between the created resources in azure portal and azure devops for seamless deployments from build and release pipelines. So, here in the second script I should get that kubeconfig file and take values like ca-cert, token, apiserver-url. So, is there a way to get those values from kubeconfig in to the terraform script. Below is the main.tf file (second terraform script) for the service connections. My main focus is there shouldn't be any manual intervention as much as possible. Thanks

```
terraform {    
  required_providers {
azuredevops = {
source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
version = "0.1.1"
}
}    
} 
   
provider "azurerm" {    
  features {}    
}

provider "azuredevops" {
#  version = ">=0.10"
  org_service_url = ""
  personal_access_token = ""
}

resource "azuredevops_project" "demo" {
  name               = "demo Project"
  visibility         = "private"
  version_control    = "Git"
  work_item_template = "Agile"
  description        = "Managed by Terraform"

  features = {
      "boards" = "enabled"
      "repositories" = "enabled"
      "pipelines" = "enabled"
      "testplans" = "enabled"
      "artifacts" = "enabled"
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes" "demo-azure" {
  project_id            = ""
  service_endpoint_name = "demo Kubernetes"
  apiserver_url         = ""
  authorization_type    = "AzureSubscription"

  azure_subscription {
    subscription_id   = ""
    subscription_name = ""
    tenant_id         = ""
    resourcegroup_id  = ""
    namespace         = "default"
    cluster_name      = ""
    cluster_admin     = true
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_resource_authorization" "demo-azure" {
  project_id  = ""
  resource_id = azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes.demo-azure.id
  authorized  = true
}

resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes" "demo-kubeconfig" {
  project_id            = ""
  service_endpoint_name = "demo Kubernetes kubeconfig"
  apiserver_url         = "
  authorization_type    = "Kubeconfig"

  kubeconfig {
    kube_config            = <<EOT
                              apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 
    server: 
  name: 
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: 
    user: 
  name: 
current-context: 
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: 
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 
    client-key-data: 
                             EOT
    accept_untrusted_certs = true
    cluster_context        = "dev-frontend"
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_resource_authorization" "demo-kubeconfig" {
  project_id  = ""
  resource_id = azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes.demo-kubeconfig.id
  authorized  = true
}

resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes" "demo-service-account" {
  project_id            = ""
  service_endpoint_name = "demo Kubernetes sa"
  apiserver_url         = ""
  authorization_type    = "ServiceAccount"

  service_account {
    token   = ""
    ca_cert = ""
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_resource_authorization" "demo-service-account" {
  project_id  = ""
  resource_id = azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes.demo-service-account.id
  authorized  = true
}
```